# I want to open a activity class from my widget class

Tags: android, android-widget

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setAction(YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
rootView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgDistiFlag, pi);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, rootView);
```

and below is the code of  onReceive function

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(YOUR_AWESOME_ACTION)) {

    Intent intn = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class);
    intn.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity (intn);

}
```

Comment: put your code on `onUpdate(...)` an try

Comment: I try that too but it is not working . @Simple plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that. For "just" opening an Activity from your widget class this will be enough:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgDistiFlag, pendingIntent);
```

Edit for your wrong Manifest declaration:

Your Widget is not an Activity so you can't set it as Activity in manifest. You must use receiver.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.wapp.MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="lbl" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_xml" />
    </receiver>
```

Your **widget_xml** file (dp values are for a 4x1 widget):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/your_widget_layout_xml">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: I tried what u suggested but it didnt work. And i check logcat but i didnt find any error . @Sir SC

Comment: can you post your onUpdate method that you tried what I suggested? It is working for me you should be missing something

Comment: 'Intent i = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
      
      PendingIntent pe = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
      rootView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgDistiFlag, pe);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, rootView);

Comment: it is wrong, you must call your Activty class in intent and rest is fine and should work. Intent i= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

Comment: Thank you but after declaring my widget provider class in manifest file . there is an error in logcat when i am clicking on imageView : error is:- **E/AndroidRuntime(17900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wapp/com.wapp.MyWidgetProvider}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.wapp.MyWidgetProvider cannot be cast to android.app.Activity**

Comment: and my manifest code is     **'<activity
            android:name="com.wapp.MyWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>'**

Comment: Widget is not an activity class. Your declaration is wrong. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thanx u were right . Thank you for u guidence . @Sir SC